# How to use <<MenuSelect>> to bind to a tkinter menu item selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I've been trying to bind a callback to a menu item selection, instead of using the command= functionality of the add_command method.

However, it seems that no matter what I try it will only give me a proper index of the menu item ("Menu 1" and "Menu 2") when they are select, instead of the index of the buttons of the menu. When the button is pressed in will just print None.

This is my current test code, but I've been trying a bunch of different stuff.

```
import tkinter as tk

def menucallback(event):
    print(root.call(event.widget, "index", "active"))

root = tk.Tk()

# create menu
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menu1 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu1.add_command(label="Button 1")
menu1.add_command(label="Button 2")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu 1", menu=menu1)

menu2 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu2.add_command(label="Button 6")
menu2.add_command(label="Button 7")

menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu 2", menu=menu2)

tk.Tk.config(root, menu=menubar)

# bind to function
menubar.bind("<<MenuSelect>>", menucallback)

root.mainloop()
```

In case it matters, I'm on Windows 7 with Python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the event to trigger on the dropdown menus, you need to add the same binding to each menu.

The reason you get none when selecting the menu item is likely because the state of the menu changes before the callback is called (ie: there is no active item after you click).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit. Now it will print the correct index when i hover over the item, but still None when i press it.


Do you have any ideas? I guess I'm somehow approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: @anderswb: like I said, when you click, the button is no longer in the active state. `<<MenuSelect>>` was designed to display context sensitive help while items are active, it wasn't designed to be used for any other purpose. Just use the `command` attribute if you need something to happen when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm messing around with creating a MVC pattern, and was trying to avoid having the view write back to the controller. Hence the binding. Thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: @BryanOakley he could store the value that is returned by MenuSelect and run a function through wait_variable. But you are right, there is no need for it when there is already a option to run a command.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe a little bit late for you, but I was on a point I thought I would need it.
In fact I do not, but maybe someone else needs it:

```
import tkinter as tk

def menucallback(event):
    check = root.call(event.widget, "index","active")
    if check != "none":
        menu_index.set(check)
def foo():
    display.configure(text=menu_index.get())
    index = menu_index.get()
    if index == 0:
        display.configure(bg='blue')
    if index == 1:
        display.configure(bg='red')
    display.wait_variable(menu_index)
    foo()
    
    

root = tk.Tk()
display = tk.Label(root, text='default')
display.pack(fill='x')

menu_index = tk.IntVar()

menubar =tk.Menu(root)
menu1 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu1.add_command(label="Button1")
menu1.add_command(label="Button2")
menubar.add_cascade(label='Menu1', menu=menu1)

menu1.bind('<<MenuSelect>>', menucallback)
tk.Tk.config(root, menu=menubar)

foo()
root.mainloop()
```

Finally found [a usefull place for that code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65889557/13629335). It can be used to create *scrolling buttons* on the menu.
**Note**
This code seems to be *Windows only* solution.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to do anything useful on OSX.

Comment: @Bryan This code just executes after clicking. It's a unnecessary way to invoke a command, like you stated. After clicking on a command it should change a colour.

Comment: Clicking did nothing for me. No color change, no errors.

Comment: That's weird, I just checked this code today and it works for MS, Windows 10. Thanks for pointing this out.