# Scrollbar for a menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, scrollbar, frame

Recently I started to work for a school project. This project has to be an app which is created using python.
Everything worked very well, without problems , but I have a blocking point now.
For the main menu of my app, I want to add a scrollbar in the right side of the interface.
This scrollbar will be used to navigate through photos, buttons and some labels.

This is the code:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)

import tkinter as tk


from functools import partial

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from QRcodepage import QRcode





class ThePage():
    
    def pageMain(self):
        MainPageClass=tk.Toplevel()
        MainPageClass.geometry('500x500')
        MainPageClass.title('MainPage')
        MainPageClass.resizable(0,0)
        MainPageClass.configure(bg='#C97E48')


        #create hamburger menu
        
        def toggle_win():
            f1=Frame(MainPageClass,width=300,height=500,bg='#262626')
            f1.place(x=300,y=0)
            #create the rest of the buttons
            def bttn(x,y,text,bcolor,fcolor,cmd):
                def on_entera(e):
                    myButton1['background']=bcolor #ffcc66
                    myButton1['foreground']='#ab6038' #000d33
                def on_leavea(e):
                    myButton1['background']=fcolor
                    myButton1['foreground']='#262626'
                
                myButton1=Button(f1,text=text,width=24,height=2,fg='#262626'
                ,border=0,bg=fcolor,activeforeground='#262626'
                ,activebackground=bcolor,command=cmd)

                myButton1.bind("<Enter>",on_entera)
                myButton1.bind("<Leave>",on_leavea)

                myButton1.place(x=x,y=y)

            def closeWindow():
                #newvar=createlogin.tkLogin
                #btn=Button(MainPageClass,command=newvar.withdraw)
                #btn.pack()
                pass
          


            bttn(13,80,'HOME','#0f9d9a','#14c4c0',None)
            bttn(13,140,'TRAINER','#0f9d9a','#14c4c0',None)
            bttn(13,200,'NUTRITIONAL PLAN','#0fd9da','#14c4c0',None)
            bttn(13,260,'PHYSICAL EVALUATION','#0fd9da','#14c4c0',None)
            bttn(13,320,'CHOOSE GYM','#0fd9da','#14c4c0',None)
            bttn(13,380,'LOG OUT','#0fd9da','#14c4c0',closeWindow)

            def dele():
                f1.destroy()

            #global img2
            #img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('x.png'))
            


            
            Button(f1,text='X',command=dele).place(x=5,y=10)

        #Creating header using Canva function



        def code():
            code=QRcode()
            code.openQR()
        
        w,h=(550,100)

        canvas=tk.Canvas(MainPageClass,height=h,width=w)
        canvas.pack()
        bg=tk.PhotoImage(file="headerbackground.png")
        bg_1=tk.Label(MainPageClass,image=bg)
        bg_1.place()


        Logo=Image.open('C:\Robert Andrei\Facultate\FEUP\Software Design\Source code\Logo2.png')
        LogoResiz=Logo.resize((100,100))
        LogoRend=ImageTk.PhotoImage(LogoResiz)
        LogoLabel=Label(MainPageClass,image=LogoRend)
        LogoLabel.place(relx=0,rely=0)



        

        
        photoHamburger=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Robert Andrei\Facultate\FEUP\Software Design\Source code\hamburger.png")
        photoHamburgerResize=photoHamburger.subsample(7,7)

        Hamburgerbtn=tk.Button(MainPageClass,image=photoHamburgerResize,command=toggle_win,text='Login',bd='0')
        Hamburgerbtn.place(relx=0.9,rely=0.1,anchor=CENTER)

        #This is the end of our code for the Canva area
        
      
        
        sb = Scrollbar(MainPageClass,orient=VERTICAL)  
        sb.pack(side = RIGHT, fill ='y') 


        TitleLabel=tk.Label(MainPageClass,text='Welcome to your digital gym friend',bg="#C97E48",font='Helvetica 14 bold',xscrollcomand=sb.set)
        TitleLabel.place(relx=0.18,rely=0.3)

        QRbutton=tk.Button(MainPageClass,text='QR Code',bd='4',command=code,xscrollcomand=sb.set)
        QRbutton.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.38)

        photoYogaclass=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Robert Andrei\Facultate\FEUP\Software Design\Source code\yoga.PNG")
        photoYogaResize=photoYogaclass.subsample(2,2)

        YogaLabel=tk.Label(MainPageClass,image=photoYogaResize,border=0,xscrollcomand=sb.set)
        YogaLabel.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.5)
        
        YogaText=tk.Label(MainPageClass,text='Yoga Class',border=0,bg='#C97E48', foreground='white',font=('Arial',14),xscrollcomand=sb.set)
        YogaText.place(relx=0.13,rely=0.7)

        photoJoin=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Robert Andrei\Facultate\FEUP\Software Design\Source code\JoinButton.PNG')
        photoJoinResize=photoJoin.subsample(1,1)

        JoinButton=tk.Button(MainPageClass,image=photoJoinResize,command=None,bd='0',bg="#C97E48",xscrollcomand=sb.set)
        JoinButton.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5)

        photoJogging=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Robert Andrei\Facultate\FEUP\Software Design\Source code\Jogging.PNG')
        photoJoggingResize=photoJogging.subsample(2,2)

        JoggingLabel=tk.Label(MainPageClass,image=photoJoggingResize,border=0,xscrollcomand=sb.set)
        JoggingLabel.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.8)

        JoggingText=tk.Label(MainPageClass,text='Jogging Class',border=0,bg='#C97E48', foreground='white',font=('Arial',14),yscrollcomand=sb.set)
        JoggingText.place(relx=0.13,rely=1.1)


    

    

        mainloop()
```

Do you can help to create a scrollbar which will help me scrolling through the interface?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Since the images aren't necessary to reproduce the problem, it would help if your example didn't require them.

Comment: [Are you looking for something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887661/how-to-insert-a-scrollbar-to-a-menu)

Comment: I don't think that it is the same. Could I contact you in private ?